# Generating a table from values in CSV file with bidirectional text

Tags: tabularx, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi, csvsimple

I want to generate a table from values inside csv file which have the following properties:

- They include bidirectional text; some columns have English text (a left-to-right language) while others contain Arabic (a right-to-left language).
- Some values are empty, and I want them appear empty too inside the table
- There is no header inside the csv file.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[margin=5mm,landscape]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% \usepackage{polyglossia}
% \setmainlanguage{arabic}
% \setotherlanguages{english}
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
% \setmonofont[Scale=1]{DejaVu Sans Mono}                          
% \setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
% \newfontfamily\englishfont{Arial}

\begin{filecontents*}{DB.csv}
1,عنوان باللغة العربية,YYY-XX-01,27,عنوان اخر,English Name,اسم شخص س
2,,UUU-ZZ-02,29,عنوان 2,English Too,اسم شخص ص
3,,BBB-GG-03,30,عنوان 3,English Term,اسم شخص و
4,,CCC-UG-04,25,عنوان عربي,English Text,اسم شخص ن
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXXXXX@{}}
  \toprule
  Heading1 &  Heading2 & Heading3 & Heading4 & Heading5 & Heading6 & Heading7 \\
  \midrule
  \csvreader[no head,%
  late after line=\\\midrule,%
  table foot=\bottomrule]%
  {DB.csv}{1=\idcode,2=\labname,3=\roomcode,4=\roomno,5=\arab,6=\eng,7=\person}%
  {\idcode & \labname & \roomcode & \roomno & \arab & \eng & \person}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**Output (Arabic text is missing)**
[image: typeset output of the MWE]

**Problems Need Solving**

- I could only get the file compiled *after* commenting `polyglossia` package and its related code (see above), but all Arabic text was not shown, when I uncomment that code, the file won't compile throwing the following error:

  ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.
  --- TeX said ---
   
                     ١
  l.37 \end{tabularx}

  --- HELP ---
  This is usually caused by a LaTeX command expecting but not finding
  either a number or a length as an argument. You may have omitted an
  argument, or a square bracket in the text may have been mistaken for
  the beginning of an optional argument. This error is also caused by
  putting \protect in front of either a length command or a command such
  as \value that produces a number.
- How to get rid of the horizontal line by the *final* `\midrule`, the one just before the `\bottomrule`?

**PS**

Solutions that use `datatool` or `pgfplotstable` package or any other package are welcome, but the most important thing is to leave the header be *manually* formatted and not automatically typeset, in my case the formatting of the header is more involved than the one showed here in the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that other packages are welcome, here's an example using `datatool`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[margin=5mm,landscape]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{datatool}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{FreeSerif}

\begin{filecontents*}{DB.csv}
1,عنوان باللغة العربية,YYY-XX-01,27,عنوان اخر,English Name,اسم شخص س
2,,UUU-ZZ-02,29,عنوان 2,English Too,اسم شخص ص
3,,BBB-GG-03,30,عنوان 3,English Term,اسم شخص و
4,,CCC-UG-04,25,عنوان عربي,English Text,اسم شخص ن
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data}{DB.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXXXXX@{}}
\toprule
\textenglish{Heading1} &  
\textenglish{Heading2} &
\textenglish{Heading3} &
\textenglish{Heading4} & 
\textenglish{Heading5} & 
\textenglish{Heading6} &
\textenglish{Heading7}
\DTLforeach*{data}{\idcode=Column1,\labname=Column2,\roomcode=Column3,%
  \roomno=Column4,\arab=Column5,\eng=Column6,\person=Column7}%
{%
  \\\midrule
  \textenglish{\idcode} & 
  \textarabic{\labname} & 
  \textenglish{\roomcode} &
  \textenglish{\roomno} &
  \textarabic{\arab} & 
  \textenglish{\eng} & 
  \textarabic{\person} 
}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Since `tabularx` processes its contents multiple times, it's more efficient to construct the contents first. For example, like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[margin=5mm,landscape]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{datatool}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{FreeSerif}

\begin{filecontents*}{DB.csv}
1,عنوان باللغة العربية,YYY-XX-01,27,عنوان اخر,English Name,اسم شخص س
2,,UUU-ZZ-02,29,عنوان 2,English Too,اسم شخص ص
3,,BBB-GG-03,30,عنوان 3,English Term,اسم شخص و
4,,CCC-UG-04,25,عنوان عربي,English Text,اسم شخص ن
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data}{DB.csv}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tabcontents}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXXXXX@{}}
 \toprule
 \textenglish{Heading1} &
 \textenglish{Heading2} &
 \textenglish{Heading3} &
 \textenglish{Heading4} &
 \textenglish{Heading5} &
 \textenglish{Heading6} &
 \textenglish{Heading7}}

\DTLforeach*{data}{\idcode=Column1,\labname=Column2,\roomcode=Column3,%
  \roomno=Column4,\arab=Column5,\eng=Column6,\person=Column7}%
{%
  \eappto\tabcontents{\noexpand\\\noexpand\midrule
  \noexpand\textenglish{\idcode} \noexpand&
  \noexpand\textarabic{\labname} \noexpand&
  \noexpand\textenglish{\roomcode} \noexpand&
  \noexpand\textenglish{\roomno} \noexpand&
  \noexpand\textarabic{\arab} \noexpand&
  \noexpand\textenglish{\eng} \noexpand&
  \noexpand\textarabic{\person}}
}%
\appto\tabcontents{\\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}}

\tabcontents

\end{document}
```

This means that the overhead incurred by `\DTLforeach` is minimised. The actual saving in terms of the document build process depends on the size of the database.

[image: image of table]

Comment: Great! could you please add `\midrule` as in the MWE? One more thing, in order to *rightly* typset the Arabic text change this line to: `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}` to glue Arabic characters with each other.

Comment: @doctorate Sorry, I missed that. Corrected.